# Retropie: Start with netplay sends me back to the menu

Tags: retropie

I'm trying to start netplay and it works on the other raspberry but on mine if I start it with netplay it sends me back to the menu. I updated everything. Anyone any suggestions

Comment: Copy that other raspberry's SD card to yours.

Comment: Kinda 1000+ km removed from each other but I'll do that next time I'm going to visit

Comment: Do you use the same Raspberry Pis?

Comment: I use the RPi 3B+ and the other person uses the RPi 3B. We've tested it with another emulator and that one seems to work. but it seems it doesn't want to work for the n64 between our two pi's. The other person has done this before with other people though and that seems to work as well.

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden On a typical Internet connection nowadays, sending a few GB over 1000+ km doesn't seem that big a deal.

Comment: Time to do some uploading it seems. Thanks for the help